# Implement a LIKE query operator for Aerospike

Tags: full-text-search, user-defined-functions, aerospike

I'm new with Aerospike. Is there any easy way to make a search with a part of text like Mysql. Example:

```
select * from test where column like '%hello%';
```

I find difficult to migrate to a NoSQL database if this common operations are not supported.
Thanks.

Comment: That common operation is one you shouldn't be using in an RDBMS either, at least if you expect to get back a result in a reasonable amount of time. LIKE can't use an index, so it has to scan the entire table. Scans on a very large set in Aerospike will be far faster than a scan of a similar sized table.

Comment: Thanks rbotzer for your answer.
It's a good technique what you propose. Although I'm still need to search for text.
I have an application that search for words or parts of words.

I think that a MongoDb suits better for this purpose and still be a NoSQL database.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

[Predicate filtering](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/predicate.html) was added in [release 3.12](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/whats-new-aerospike-3-12/). You can use the [stringRegex](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/query/PredExp.html#stringRegex(int)) method of the [PredExp](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/query/PredExp.html) class of the Java client to implement an equivalent to LIKE. Predicate filters also currently exists for the [C](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/c/d9/d10/as__predexp_8h_source.html), [C#](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/csharp/html/T_Aerospike_Client_PredExp.htm) and [Go](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/master/predexp.go) clients.

This [example](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/examples/src/com/aerospike/examples/QueryPredExp.java#L203-L211) in the Aerospike Java client shows something similar:

```
    Statement stmt = new Statement();
    stmt.setNamespace(params.namespace);
    stmt.setSetName(params.set);        
    stmt.setFilter(Filter.range(binName, begin, end));
    stmt.setPredExp(
        PredExp.stringBin("bin3"),
        PredExp.stringValue("prefix.*suffix"),
        PredExp.stringRegex(RegexFlag.ICASE | RegexFlag.NEWLINE)
        );
```

If you're using a language client that doesn't yet support predicate filtering, you'd implement this with a [stream UDF](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/developing_stream_udfs.html) attached to a scan or query. For example, in the Python client you would create an instance of class [aerospike.Query](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/query.html) with or without a predicate and call the [aerospike.Query.apply()](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/query.html#aerospike.Query.apply) method.

Ideally you would accelerate this by bucketing and using a predicate to narrow down your search, rather than scanning the entire set. For example, you can create a startswith bin that holds the first letter, use the predicate to find that, then send the records matched through the stream UDF. Just note that a LIKE is a horribly slow operation on an RDBMS, as well, because it can't use an index.

```
local function bin_like(bin, val, plain)
    return function(rec)
        if rec[bin] and type(rec[bin]) == "string" then
            if string.find(rec[bin], val, 1, plain) then
                return true
            else
                return false
        else
            return false
        end
    end
end

local function map_record(rec)
  local ret = map()
  for i, bin_name in ipairs(record.bin_names(rec)) do
    ret[bin_name] = rec[bin_name]
  end
  return ret
end

function check_bins_match(stream, bin, val, plain)
  return stream : filter(bin_like(bin, val, plain)) : map(map_record)
end
```